# How do I display an element that should overflow the parent container?

Tags: html, css, dom, gwt

I have following HTML:

```
<g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.container}">
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

I want to display another div in which will exceed the parent container's top.
Above code is the parent widget which is assigned top and height property dynamically (this is attached to a flow panel). So each time mouse if over above parent widget, I need to display a child div which sometimes exceeds parent's top, but currently it gets cut off...
Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css overflow property. It sounds like you are looking for overflow: visible
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: Actually you were right....... setting an over flow of the parent let the child widget to extend the parent boundary. Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the negative margin on child div:

```
margin-top: -50px;
```

If your parent is absolute positioned then you could also do this in your child:

```
position: absolute:
top: -50px;
```